# If y= f(x) = lnx then can ln(x) be a point on a curve?

Tags: calculus, limits

So, I was watching this video. [Calculus](https://youtu.be/m8yC7kR5Fuk?t=10)

here, the narrator says, if f(x) = lnx. Then what is f(e)?
Later in the video the narrator takes lnx as a point on the y axis. If lnx itself is a curve then how come it be a point in the way the narrator uses it in this picture.

Am I missing something or is it the opposite?

[image]

Comment: (e,1) is the point on the curve ln x.

Comment: @insipidintegrator   Yes, that is clear to me. I don't understand this lnx part. 

is it like let's assume a point which is ln(x*) ?

Comment: "ln(x)" is not a point. For every real $x>0$ , $(x,\ln(x))$ is a point of the curve.

Comment: @Ghost ln x is actually a set of points.

Comment: @Peter then why does the narrator use it a point?

Comment: I have to assume two points for the secent line right? If so then should not be those two points look like this (x*, ln(x*) ) ?

Comment: This video should be evidence enough that it is simply not a good idea to watch math videos , unless one only wants to be entertained. The slopiness the matter is presented is usually just unbelievable. Most extreme example with extreme many (undeserved!) viewers is the video about the "equation" $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$

Comment: @Peter Then can you tell me how I should learn calculus? Because the books are so dry and sometimes make no sense at all. I am fairly new to it. Also, I am having a comeback in the math world after 2 years.

Comment: Also, this f(x) = lnx confuses me the most. Is it lnx is another version of y or it is simply y = lnx?

Comment: "$\ln x$" is just a shortcut , I would however still prefer "$\ln(x)$". "$y=\ln(x)$" and "$f(x)=\ln(x)$" mean basically the same , they define the function mapping every positive $x$ to its natural logarithm.

Comment: @Peter I am sorry for being vague. I think I could not express my concerns clearly. My apologies. What I wanted to know is ln(x) act like a function? Because it seems like a function. It takes a value of x and gives an output just like f(x). 
However, it feels like in the video it is being treated as x  like y =x or f(x) = x.

Comment: $f(x)=\ln(x)$ is a function, it is just not defined for $x\le 0$. For every positive $x$ , the output is uniquely defined , so it is a function. It is of course much more complicated than the trivial function $f(x)=x$ , but in principle nothing different (apart from having another domain)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question: in the video, the narrator says "what is $f'(e)$", not "$f(e)$". He says, correctly, that "the point $(e,1)=(e,\ln(e))$ lies on the curve", meaning that the curve is the function that maps $x>0$ to the couple $(x,\ln(x))$. Geometrically, the tangent line refers to a curve, analytically, to a function. But, basically, the reason why you talk about "slope of the tangent" is because **the graph** of $y=f(x)$ is a curve, not $f(x)$ itself.

Comment: Does that mean that the author completely misintepreted the video (I did not watch it, I trusted the author) ?

Comment: By author do you mean me?

Comment: With "author" I mean the author of the question , not the author of the video.

Comment: Ok! so the equation itself is a curve but the entities can be treated as points. Am I right?

Comment: By definition, a (plain) curve is a function to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The equation $y=f(x)$ denotes a function, the equation $\gamma(t)=(t,f(t))$ denotes the curve (and characterizes the graph of $f$, which is a curve).